# WCF Web Service Hosted in SharePoint 2010 browser blank page response

Tags: wcf, rest, sharepoint-2010, web-config

I'm facing a problem with SharePoint 2010 custom web service.
The service is an SVC installed and deployed on the system: without particular configuration it works but I need to customize the web.config to achieve some security roles.

The problems is that when I try to invoke methods from browser the response is empty.

This is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
<service name="SharePointWCFService.GetListData" 
behaviorConfiguration="WCFBasicHttpBinding.Service1Behavior">
<endpoint address="http://address" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SharePointWCFService.IGetListData">
<identity>
<dns value="localhost"/>
</identity>
</endpoint>
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/> 
<endpoint address="http://address" binding="WebHttpBinding" contract="SharePointWCFService.IGetListData" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
</service>
 </services>
 <behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
 <behavior name="WCFBasicHttpBinding.Service1Behavior">
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>

<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
 </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel> 
 </configuration>
```

This is the interface I'm implementing:

```
[ServiceContract]
 public interface IGetListData
 {
   [OperationContract]
   [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
   JSonResult GetJsonResponse(string data);
```

}

And this the class

```
[BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpointAttribute]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
class GetListData : IGetListData
{
    private const string Admin_Svc_GetListData = "Admin_Svc_GetListData";

    public JSonResult GetJsonResponse(string data)
    {
        return new JSonResult()
        {
            Firstname = "MyFirstname",
            Lastname = "MyLastname"
        };
    } //  public JSonResult GetJsonResponse(string data)
```

Do I must declare something different at web.config side?

Comment: Is it just me or both service endpoints have same address?

Comment: I have removed it, now I put in a fake address.. In my config has the same value.. Is this a problem?

Comment: No, actually, what you put in the address is ignored because it is IIS hosting. So, the address is actually the URL path to your SVC file. What you've done is enabled two endpoints with 2 bindings for the same address (which is path to your SVC). I think you have to remove one of the endpoints.